# Number and string sorting Al

Tags: java, c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to sort some number+string combination but the sorting will be based on the number from that combination. Can you suggest an optimal solution?

Say my strings are:

12 Masdf

4 Oasd

44 Twer

and so on. The sorting will be based on the numbers like 12, 4, 44 and after the sorting I have to show the full alphanumeric strings.

As the program will run on thousands of data I don't want to split the string and compare the number on each iteration. My plan is to extract the numbers and take those in an array and then sort the array. After sorting done, I want to put back the numbers with associated strings and keep those in a string array to show.
It should be done in C++. Algorithms should be applied - Insertion sort, Quick sort, Merge sort, etc.

Comment: Easily solvable with `std::map`/`std::multimap`.

Comment: @bku_drytt  unless, of course, the homework assignment is to make the classes that do this.   The last sentence of his problem description makes me think the prof wants it implemented with various sort algorithms.   AFAIK (and I'm not really an expert in `std::`) you can only provide a comparison function, not the sort function, leading me to believe the assignment is more than just use `std::map`

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to store the full string and the number. Make the class `Comparable`. Convert your list of string to list of Class. Sort the list using which sort method is relevant. Iterate the list and print the string fields.

Sorry, that was an answer for Java, since you tagged it Java. Replace/remove `Comparable` for whatever is good for C++.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume these two parts are in separate variables and are not together as one string (if they were you could just store them in a list).

First consider a Map. Each 'bucket' of the map can be represented by a number. Within each of the maps buckets is a bunch of strings in a list. (Note this could also be solved with an array especially if the Integer part is always under some fixed value) The java equivalent would look like:

```
    Map map = new HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>>();
```

For sorting on this custom collection first the integer part of the value would be searched on the map returning a list. Every item in the list will have the same starting number. So we now search the list the string part of the value (I am assuming the list is sorted so you can do whatever sort you want ie: selection/quicksort).

The advantages of this search mean that if the number is not found in the Hashmap you instantly know there is no string part for it.